# One function isn't executing when I use the Soundcloud Javascript API

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm using the example code from the Soundcloud documentation:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: CLIENT_ID,
  redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
});
SC.connect(function() {
  SC.get('/me', function(me) { 
    alert('Hello, ' + me.username); 
  });
});
```

I'm getting a popup window asking me to sign in, and then before it alerts me it is redirecting me to the Redirect URI. Am I doing something wrong here, why is there no alert? Also, how do I close the pop up window after it goes to the Redirect URI?

Comment: Documentation says *"You'll have to host the callback.html file on your server and set the redirect_uri in your app settings accordingly"*. Do you have this on your server?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Squarespace but I did upload the file on my server.